# Dynamic queryName in graphql

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, graphql, apollo-client

I had a common dropdown component which gets graphql queryname based on requirement and it should accept it and sent to actions and after grapqlAPI where it recieve it and call api dynamcally

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

export const FETCH_REFERENCE_DATA1 = (typeName) => {
  console.log(typeName)
  return typeName;
}
export const FETCH_REFERENCE_DATA = gql`
  query findQuery($locale: Locale!) {
    ${FETCH_REFERENCE_DATA1}(locale: $locale) {
      presentation
      _desc
    }
  }
`;
```

Some Thing like this I tried but its throwing error

```
GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "=".
▶ 12 stack frames were collapsed.
parseDocument
C:/Projects/src/index.ts:96
Module.gql
C:/Projects/src/index.ts:133
Module.<anonymous>
C:/Projects/frontend-main-app/src/queries/referenceTables.ts:7
   4 |   console.log(typeName)
   5 |   return typeName;
   6 | }
>  7 | export const FETCH_REFERENCE_DATA = gql`
   8 |   query findQuery($locale: Locale!) {
   9 |     ${FETCH_REFERENCE_DATA1}(locale: $locale) {
  10 |       presentationstrong text
```

Comment: You're using a function where it should be a string for the name, I'm not sure what's the intent of the function, but it's clearly not going to work.

Comment: You should use `useLazyQuery`, but as @EmileBergeron wrote your query is not valid.

Comment: @EmileBergeron even I just use  a variable not  function it is not working..same error

Comment: @DaniR do you have any code snippet for that how to use

Comment: @DaniR  I tried like this import { gql, useLazyQuery } from '@apollo/client';

 const FETCH_REFERENCE_DATA = gql`
  query findQuery($locale: Locale!) {
    findCurrency(locale: $locale) {
      presentation
      _desc
    }
  }`;


export function FETCH_REFERENCE_DATA12() {
  const x = useLazyQuery(FETCH_REFERENCE_DATA);
  console.log(x, "ss");
} but getting this error You must wrap the query string in a "gql" tag.
new InvariantError

Comment: @DaniR @EmileBergeron export const FETCH_REFERENCE_DATA = (typeName: string) => {
  return gql`query findQuery($locale: Locale!) {
    ${typeName}(locale: $locale) {
      presentation
      _desc
    }
  }`
  }   I tried this way its working and taking that typename and calling api but it is calling continously

Comment: different problem, bad hook usage, read docs/tuts

Comment: @xadm I fixed my useEffect and its working fine .. thank you all